# R - Get a matrix with the reduced number of features with SVD

Tags: r, feature-extraction, svd, dimensionality-reduction, matrix-factorization

I'm using the SVD package with R and I'm able to reduce the dimensionality of my matrix by replacing the lowest singular values by 0. But when I recompose my matrix I still have the same number of features, I could not find how to effectively delete the most useless features of the source matrix in order to reduce it's number of columns.

For example what I'm doing for the moment:

This is my source matrix A:

```
  A B C D
1 7 6 1 6
2 4 8 2 4
3 2 3 2 3
4 2 3 1 3
```

If I do:

```
s = svd(A)
s$d[3:4] = 0  # Replacement of the 2 smallest singular values by 0
A' = s$u %*% diag(s$d)  %*% t(s$v)
```

I get A' which has the same dimensions (4x4), was reconstruct with only 2 "components" and is an approximation of A (containing a little bit less information, maybe less noise, etc.):

```
      [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]
1 6.871009 5.887558 1.1791440 6.215131
2 3.799792 7.779251 2.3862880 4.357163
3 2.289294 3.512959 0.9876354 2.386322
4 2.408818 3.181448 0.8417837 2.406172
```

What I want is a sub matrix with less columns but reproducing the distances between the different rows, something like this (obtained using PCA, let's call it A''):

```
        PC1        PC2
1 -3.588727  1.7125360
2 -2.065012 -2.2465708
3  2.838545  0.1377343   # The similarity between rows 3 
4  2.815194  0.3963005   # and 4 in A is conserved in A''
```

Here is the code to get A'' with PCA:

```
p = prcomp(A)
A'' = p$x[,1:2]
```

The final goal is to reduce the number of columns in order to speed up clustering algorithms on huge datasets.

Thank you in advance if someone can guide me :)

Comment: You should construct an example matrix with some small eigenvalues to be set to 0, to help show what you want to accomplish and what you're getting with the `svd` approach.  Otherwise you force each person who attempts to answer the question to do this.

Comment: Hello Matthew, I edited my question, there is now a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [this chapter on dimensionality reduction](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch11.pdf) or [this cross-validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64370/how-to-use-svd-for-dimensionality-reduction). The idea is that the entire data set can be reconstructed using less information. It's not like PCA in the sense that you might only choose to keep 2 out of 10 principal components.

When you do the kind of trimming you did above, you're really just taking out some of the "noise" of your data. The data still as the same dimension.

Comment: Hello MrFlick, 
Thank you for your reply, indeed in what I did and in the pages you have referred, one is doing a reconstruction of the matrix with the same size but with less information.

But what I want to know is, if there is a way from a source matrix to create a submatrix with less columns that reproduce the distances between the rows in the original matrix using SVD?

Comment: @ClydeX I cannot find any examples of that. Is there a reason you believe it should work that way?

Comment: The only reason is that PCA use SVD so it should be possible to do the factor analysis based on the SVD output manually. The idea was to better understand the link between SVD and PCA.

Comment: If the idea is to better understand a statistical method, then that's not really a specific programming question. You might have better luck asking your question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/